# MAC OS and Arduino IDE updated fails to compile ESP-12E NodeMCU 1.0

Tags: macos, arduino

MAC OS updated last night to macOS version 10.15 Beta.
Today, Arduino IDE will not compile a sketch, even after
again downloading and installing the latest ARDUINO 1.8.9.

"Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)"
Worked yesterday.

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Mac OS X), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4M (1M SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 230400"

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/gregbaker/Desktop/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=disabled,ssl=all,eesz=4M1M,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=230400 -vid-pid=10C4_EA60 -ide-version=10809 -build-path /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_cache_554397 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.python.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python/3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.python-3.7.2-post1.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python/3.7.2-post1 -verbose /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/esp8266/examples/Blink/Blink.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/gregbaker/Desktop/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:nodemcuv2:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=disabled,ssl=all,eesz=4M1M,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=230400 -vid-pid=10C4_EA60 -ide-version=10809 -build-path /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_cache_554397 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-2.5.0-3-20ed2b9.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9 -prefs=runtime.tools.python.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python/3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.python-3.7.2-post1.path=/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python/3.7.2-post1 -verbose /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/libraries/esp8266/examples/Blink/Blink.ino
Using board 'nodemcuv2' from platform in folder: /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2
Using core 'esp8266' from platform in folder: /Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2
Detecting libraries used...
/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/sdk/include -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378/core -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK221=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU\"" -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266 -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/variants/nodemcu /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
Generating function prototypes...
/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/sdk/include -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378/core -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK221=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10809 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU\"" -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266 -I/Users/gregbaker/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/variants/nodemcu /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /var/folders/jp/j5yxgdcj2k5dqfw8lp3hrfzc0000gp/T/arduino_build_124378/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
fork/exec /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags: bad CPU type in executable
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

Aside from turning off automatic updates, 
any thoughts and/or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's because MacOS only run 64-bit apps, while Arduino IDE run in 32-bit.
the **solution** would be you just have to load the newer version of Arduino IDE which in **beta** here.
[link to the beta version for mac.](http://downloads.arduino.cc/javaide/pull_requests/arduino-PR-8976-BUILD-869-macosx.zip)